# Should I use smallint or numeric(4,0) to store a year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, sqldatatypes

I have a limited amount of RAM available on my server. I've read about using smallint to store a year here but I was wondering if using a fixed precision number would be better on Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: i would recommend `smallint`

Comment: I would recommend using a DATE datatype instead. It will make everything easier in the long run if you use dates instead of ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data type will take up storage space, not RAM.  `Smallint` ranges from -2^15 (-32,768) to 2^15-1 (32,767) so that would probably satisfy your need.

You can see the difference in bytes between [decimal/numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx), [float/real](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx), and the various [ints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: It will be an in-memory table and yes I know that smallint is enough. But is numeric(4,0) smaller ?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeBrabant `smallint` takes 2 bytes where `numeric` with a precision from 1-9 takes 5 bytes, so no it is not.